# Short story where an astronaut has 3 personalities

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm trying to recall a short story based around a spaceship pilot who's never flown in space - at least not consciously.  As soon as he enters the ship's flight deck, John's second personality takes over, flies the ship to its destination, lands, and "John 1" re-emerges and goes on his merry way.

Of course, in the course of the story, this tidy arrangement goes awry and John's *third* personality is called upon to save the day.

Comment: Is it the same as [this story](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/151305/very-old-sci-fi-short-story-where-astronauts-have-an-unconscious-personality-c) and [this one](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/124273/short-story-spaceship-pilot-needs-second-personality-to-fly-ship)?

Comment: If so, it has been identified as ["Captain Bedlam"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?62849) by [Harry Harrison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Harrison_(writer)).

Comment: But no closing as a duplicate please, until we have confirmation.

Comment: You can read it at [archive.org](https://archive.org/stream/New_Worlds_069v23_1958-03#page/n67/mode/2up). If this is the right story please let us know with a comment.

Comment: Phill W. - a flight deck is the control space of an airplane, a bridge is the control space of a ship, and in science fiction the control room is the control space of a space ship.  The term bridge should not be used in science fiction except in series like Star Trek that already use it and flight deck should never be used since space ships don't fly, they travel in outer space.